# Is it possible to have a Kafka cluster with different OSes?

Tags: apache-kafka

If I have one Kafka running on Windows server, and another Kafka running on Linux server, and the last one running on a Unix server, can I use those three as one cluster?

Server A  - Windows
Server B  - Linux
Server C  - Unix

Can I use them for replication? As in `--replication-factor 3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brokers communicate via well defined APIs that don't depend on the operating system, so in theory that should work. However, I doubt anybody has tried running such a cluster!

It's worth noting that Windows is not an officially supported platform: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#os so you may run into a few issues.

I'm not sure why you'd even consider doing this as this sounds like an operation nightmare! For science!

Comment: Thank you.  I wanted to test clustering with 3, but I don't have testing resources, so I might have to scavenge servers at work :)  (Not in production for sure) I'll keep that in mind.  I am running Kafka on Windows and I kind of know what you mean.

Comment: @JinLee Why don't you use Docker (e.g. [docker-kafka](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker) or [Confluent Platform Quick Start (Docker)](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html))? As long as the machine is powerful enough, you should easily a 3-broker Kafka cluster.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski   Can I make 3 broker cluster with Docker?  I am running Confluent Platform docker in one of my servers. I didn't know I can make 3 brokers with one docker.  If one Docker goes down, won't all three go down though? Could you kindly give me some advice on how to cluster with dockers as answers? I'll upvote for sure! :)